# Temperature coefficient of Emitter voltage of a NPN transistor

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

This problem is from a book "Microelectronic circuits - Theory and applications" 7e by Sedra, smith , oxford university press on page 275. I am trying to find the variation of emitter voltage with temperature using any suitable method. The description of temperature coefficient is not given in the book. I looked in some application notes such as below which gave some idea. Generally in some problems, the temperature coefficient is given as \$V_{BE}\$. In this problem, we are required to find the temperature coefficient for \$V_E\$ and calculate that voltage with change in temperature. From a circuit perspective, the variation of voltage with temperature may be looked at as variation of resistance with temperature looking from the node E by calculating its thevenin equivalent. It seems that there is more to transistor properties than variation of thevenin resistance looking from E. Can anybody explain how to calculate the temperature coefficient for \$V_E\$?

The application notes I used which you can also look are:

https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/application_note_en_20210331_AKX00049.pdf?did=63510

https://www.planetanalog.com/temperature-coefficients-negative-vs-positive/

The problem is below:

In the circuit shown in Figure, current source I = 1 mA at 25°C with β = 100. What current flows in \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$? What voltage would you expect at node E? Noting that the temperature coefficient of \$V_{BE}\$ for \$I_E\$ constant is - 2mV/°C. What is the temperature coefficient of \$V_E\$? For a ambient temperature of 75°C, what voltage would you expect at node E? Clearly state any simplifying assumptions you make

[image]

Comment: Is your question reliant on people answering who have access to the Sedra book?

Comment: Somebody who knows transistor design might be able to answer. There is not much information given about temperature coefficient given in that book or any other book. There are some application notes on NPN and PNP transistors which give some info on temperature variation effects.

Comment: The thing is that you might get an improved response if you didn't appear to target the sedra book users. Do you understand ebers moll equation?

Comment: I am looking at that equation. I am trying to not to base the question on sedra and smith readers.

Comment: There is a wee hint there about "simplifying assumptions". Can you come up with any that might make the problem trivial?

Comment: Your circuit looks rather strange - are you sure that you want r2 not to be connected to ground? More than that, in a realistic circuit there is a resistor between ground and the meitter - not an idealized block like an ideal current source.

Comment: LvW, R2 is not connected to ground. The current source had a open terminal at bottom.I connected it to ground. The node E is just open. The circuit is as it was shown.

Comment: Spehro Pefhany ,Simplifying assumptions may mean that  the equivalent temperature coefficient for \$V_E\$ may be derived from temperature coefficient from \$V_{BE}\$ using some type of circuit simplification and perhaps with the currents \$I_C\$, \$I_E\$ and \$I_B\$ can be assumed to exist or be zero.

Comment: \$ \Delta V_E \approx - 2mV/°C  \times (1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2} ) \approx  -22mV/°C\$

Comment: G36, you can write the answer. below Please derive the complete expression on how you got \$ (1 + \frac{R1}{R2} )\$ .

Comment: Look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449914/vbe-multiplier-with-emitter-resistance-cancellation

Comment: Or notice that If Vbe drops by - 2mV/°C this means that the current through R1 will also drop by the same number, so the R2 voltage will drop by -2mV/R1 * R2 = -2mV * R2/R1. Do you see it?